# Tensorflow does not follow the LEGB-rule of python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am going through a tensorflow implementation of the inception network and come across the following implementation of the inception module. The first element of the inception module is the conv11 which will be stacked with conv33 and conv55 to form the output of the inception module. Prior to the conv33 and conv55 operations, the input of the inception module goes through a 1 x 1 filter operation (called conv_33_reduce and conv_55_reduce) to reduce the depth (bottleneck operation)

```
@add_arg_scope
def inception_layer(conv_11_size, conv_33_reduce_size, conv_33_size,
                    conv_55_reduce_size, conv_55_size, pool_size,
                    layer_dict, inputs=None,
                    bn=False, wd=0, init_w=None,
                    pretrained_dict=None, trainable=True, is_training=True,
                    name='inception'):

    if inputs is None:
        inputs = layer_dict['cur_input']
    layer_dict['cur_input'] = inputs

    arg_scope = tf.contrib.framework.arg_scope
    with arg_scope([L.conv], layer_dict=layer_dict, pretrained_dict=pretrained_dict,
                   bn=bn, nl=tf.nn.relu, init_w=init_w, trainable=trainable,
                   is_training=is_training, wd=wd, add_summary=False):


        conv_11 = L.conv(filter_size=1, out_dim=conv_11_size,
                         inputs=inputs, name='{}_1x1'.format(name))

        L.conv(filter_size=1, out_dim=conv_33_reduce_size,
               inputs=inputs, name='{}_3x3_reduce'.format(name))
```

**The input of the conv_33 should be 'layer_dict' from the output of the above L.conv which is the bottleneck operation to reduce the depth of the tensor; however, the output of the above L.conv is not defined**

```
        conv_33 = L.conv(filter_size=3, out_dim=conv_33_size,
                         name='{}_3x3'.format(name))

        L.conv(filter_size=1, out_dim=conv_55_reduce_size,
               inputs=inputs, name='{}_5x5_reduce'.format(name))
```

**Similarly, the output of the above L.conv is not defined for conv_55 operation**

```
        conv_55 = L.conv(filter_size=5, out_dim=conv_55_size,
                         name='{}_5x5'.format(name))

        L.max_pool(layer_dict=layer_dict, inputs=inputs, stride=1,
                   filter_size=3, padding='SAME', name='{}_pool'.format(name))
        convpool = L.conv(filter_size=1, out_dim=pool_size,
                          name='{}_pool_proj'.format(name))

        output = tf.concat([conv_11, conv_33, conv_55, convpool], 3,
                           name='{}_concat'.format(name))
        layer_dict['cur_input'] = output
        layer_dict[name] = output
    return output
```

And here is the code for the L.conv which defines the convolution operation. The output of the L.conv is a dictionary called 'layer_dict' which should be fed into the next L.conv as an input. However, in the above method of 'inception_layer', the output of the L.conv is not defined for both conv_33 and conv_55 operation. **My question is since layer_dict is a local object, how does the following conv_33 and conv_55 get access to the updated layer_dict?**

```
@add_arg_scope
def conv(filter_size,
         out_dim,
         layer_dict,
         inputs=None,
         pretrained_dict=None,
         stride=1,
         dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1],
         bn=False,
         nl=tf.identity,
         init_w=None,
         init_b=tf.zeros_initializer(),
         use_bias=True,
         padding='SAME',
         pad_type='ZERO',
         trainable=True,
         is_training=None,
         wd=0,
         name='conv',
         add_summary=False):
    if inputs is None:
        inputs = layer_dict['cur_input']
    stride = get_shape4D(stride)
    in_dim = inputs.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    filter_shape = get_shape2D(filter_size) + [in_dim, out_dim]

    if padding == 'SAME' and pad_type == 'REFLECT':
        pad_size_1 = int((filter_shape[0] - 1) / 2)
        pad_size_2 = int((filter_shape[1] - 1) / 2)
        inputs = tf.pad(
            inputs,
            [[0, 0], [pad_size_1, pad_size_1], [pad_size_2, pad_size_2], [0, 0]],
            "REFLECT")
        padding = 'VALID'

    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        if wd > 0:
            regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=wd)
        else:
            regularizer=None

        if pretrained_dict is not None and name in pretrained_dict:
            try:
                load_w = pretrained_dict[name][0]
            except KeyError:
                load_w = pretrained_dict[name]['weights']
            print('Load {} weights!'.format(name))

            load_w = np.reshape(load_w, filter_shape)
            init_w = tf.constant_initializer(load_w)

        weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                                  filter_shape,
                                  initializer=init_w,
                                  trainable=trainable,
                                  regularizer=regularizer)
        if add_summary:
            tf.summary.histogram(
                'weights/{}'.format(name), weights, collections = ['train'])

        outputs = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs,
                               filter=weights,
                               strides=stride,
                               padding=padding,
                               use_cudnn_on_gpu=True,
                               data_format="NHWC",
                               dilations=dilations,
                               name='conv2d')

        if use_bias:
            if pretrained_dict is not None and name in pretrained_dict:
                try:
                    load_b = pretrained_dict[name][1]
                except KeyError:
                    load_b = pretrained_dict[name]['biases']
                print('Load {} biases!'.format(name))

                load_b = np.reshape(load_b, [out_dim])
                init_b = tf.constant_initializer(load_b)

            biases = tf.get_variable('biases',
                                 [out_dim],
                                 initializer=init_b,
                                 trainable=trainable)
            outputs += biases

        if bn is True:
            outputs = batch_norm(outputs, train=is_training, name='bn')

        layer_dict['cur_input'] = nl(outputs)
        layer_dict[name] = layer_dict['cur_input']
        return layer_dict['cur_input']
```